# backgroundmaillibrary not sending Emails

Tags: java, android, eclipse, email, sendmail

here is my Main class:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

BackgroundMail bm = new BackgroundMail(MainActivity.this);
bm.setGmailUserName("youremail@gmail.com");
bm.setGmailPassword("yourpassword");
bm.setMailTo("receivermail id");
bm.setFormSubject("Backgroundmail");
bm.setFormBody("TEsting");
bm.setSendingMessage("Sending mail...");
bm.setSendingMessageSuccess("Your message was sent successfully.");
bm.setProcessVisibility(true);
bm.send();

}    
}
```

also I have already added the following to my Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My problem is that email is not being send from my Gmail account, (Note:- I do not have two step verification turned on)

Thanks